# Python Splinter : how to take a screenshot of full page?

Tags: python, splinter

As per splinter docs to

Take a full view screenshot:

```
browser = Browser()
screenshot_path = browser.screenshot('absolute_path/your_screenshot.png', full=True)
```

I am using the same code but it throws

> TypeError: screenshot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'full'

Here is the code -

```
from splinter import Browser
import time

with Browser('chrome') as browser:

url = "http://www.google.com"
browser.visit(url)
browser.fill('q', 'List of top IT firms')

button = browser.find_by_name('btnG')

button.click()

browser.screenshot('D:/sss/your_screenshot1.png', full=True)
time.sleep(3)
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
browser.screenshot('D:/sss/your_screenshot2.png', full=True)
```

Please help me here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you're using an older version with a different interface. What version are you using?

Comment: splinter version - 0.8.0 and selenium version - 3.13.0 @Kevin

Comment: Maybe the Browser object is being imported from the wrong module. Please provide a [mcve], including import statements.

Comment: Please check the code part @Kevin

Comment: Interesting. https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/master/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py#L504 indicates that the `full` keyword should be supported by all WebDriver objects. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong class... What does `print(type(browser))` say?

Comment: print(type(browser)) says <class 'splinter.driver.webdriver.chrome.WebDriver'>

Comment: full page screenshots are no longer possible in selenium (the library Splinter uses for browser interaction)

Comment: But if the problem was with Selenium and not Splinter, then it's unusual that the stack trace mentions the `full` keyword at all.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking into this, and found the answer right here :
https://github.com/douglasmiranda/splinter-examples/blob/master/another_examples/screenshot.py

In a nutshell : `browser.driver.save_screenshot('test.png')` is the way to go !